# How to add Element inside another list of class type which contain the list in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to add element to ChartIntakelist.

```
List<MappingAccessRightModel> listAccessRights = new List<MappingAccessRightModel>();
foreach (var item in accessRights)
{
    listAccessRights.Add(new MappingAccessRightModel
    {
        Application = item.Application,
        ListAccessRights = new List<AccessRightModel> { 
            new AccessRightModel{
                Application = item.Application,
                Id = item.ID,
                Name = item.Name,
                ChartIntakelist = new List<ChartIntake>().Add(new ChartIntake{ChartIntakeID = item.ID , ChartIntakeName = item.Name})
            }
        }
    });
}

public class AccessRightModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }

    public string GroupName { get; set; }

    public List<AccessRightModel> AccessRight { get; set; }
    public List<ChartIntake> ChartIntakelist { get; set; } 

}

public class ChartIntake 
{
    public int ChartIntakeID { get; set; }
    public string ChartIntakeName { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

The below image show the error which I am facing I want to add element of list inside the list element.

`listAccessRights` is the list which contain the `chartIntakeList`-property .
I want to add element to `ChartIntakeList`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [collection initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax.  What you are currently trying to do is set your list to the result of the `Add` method, which is `void` - this won't work.

```
ChartIntakelist = new List<ChartIntake>
{
    new ChartIntake{ChartIntakeID = item.ID , ChartIntakeName = item.Name}
}
```